# Open text file, loop through contents and check against

Tags: c#, io, openfiledialog

So I have a generic number check that I am trying to implement:

```
    public static bool isNumberValid(string Number)
    {
    }
```

And I want to read the contents of a textfile (only contains numbers) and check each line for the number and verify it is the valid number using `isNumberValid`. Then I want to output the results to a new textfile, I got this far:

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int size = -1;
        DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(); // Show the dialog.
        if (result == DialogResult.OK) // Test result.
        {
            string file = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            try
            {
                string text = File.ReadAllText(file);
                size = text.Length;
                using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(text))
                {

                        foreach (int number in text)
                        {
                            // check against isNumberValid
                            // write the results to a new textfile 
                        }
                    }
                }

            catch (IOException)
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

Kind of stuck from here if anyone can help?

The textfile contains several numbers in a list:

> 4564
>
> 4565
>
> 4455

etc.

The new textfile I want to write would just be the numbers with true or false appended to the end:

> 4564 true

Comment: Do you have some kind of separation between numbers? How is formatted a line in the input file?

Comment: What is the result you want to write to the new file?

Comment: true or false, the textfile is just a list of numbers each line has the same amount of numbers. Will update answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this to keep with the pattern you were initially following...

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(); // Show the dialog.
    if (result == DialogResult.OK) // Test result.
    {
        string file = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        try
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(file))
            {
                using (var writer = new StreamWriter("results.txt"))
                {
                    string currentNumber;
                    while ((currentNumber = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        if (IsNumberValid(currentNumber))
                            writer.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} true", currentNumber));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        catch (IOException)
        {
        }
    }
}

public bool IsNumberValid(string number)
{
    //Whatever code you use to check your number
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to read the entire file into memory all at once. You can write:

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(outputPath))
{
    foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(filename)
    {
        foreach (var num in line.Split(','))
        {
            writer.Write(num + " ");
            writer.WriteLine(IsNumberValid(num));
        }
    }
}
```

The primary advantage here is a much smaller memory footprint, as it only loads a small part of the file at a time.

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace your loop to look like this:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);
foreach (var s in lines)
{
  int number = int.Parse(s);
  ...
}
```

This would read each line of file, assuming that there is only one number per line,
and lines are separated with CRLF symbols. And parse each number to integer, assuming that integer is not greater than  2,147,483,647 and not less than  -2,147,483,648, and integers are stored in your locale settings, with or without group separators.

In case if any line is empty, or contains non-integer - code will throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

First, load all lines of the input file in a string array,
then open the output file and loop over the array of strings,

Split each line at the space separator and pass every part to your static method.

The static method use [Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) to determine if you have a valid integer or not without throwing an exception if the input text is not a valid Int32 number.

Based on the result of the method write to the output file the desidered text.

```
// Read all lines in memory (Could be optimized, but for this example let's go with a small file)
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);
// Open the output file
using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(outputFile))
{
    // Loop on every line loaded from the input file
    // Example "1234 ABCD 456 ZZZZ 98989"
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        // Split the current line in the wannabe numbers
        string[] numParts = line.Split(' ');

        // Loop on every part and pass to the validation
        foreach(string number in numParts)
        {
            // Write the result to the output file
            if(isNumberValid(number))
               writer.WriteLine(number + " True");
            else
               writer.WriteLine(number + " False");
        }
    }
}

// Receives a string and test if it is a Int32 number
public static bool isNumberValid(string Number)
{
    int result;
    return Int32.TryParse(Number, out result);
}
```

Of course this works only if your definition of 'number' is equal to the allowed values for a Int32 datatype

Comment: This doesnt check against isNumberValid tho? For instance if I want to loop thru each line in my textfile and check the number is valid your method wont do this? I am trying to check that each line in the textfile is one of the valid numbers in isValidNumber if it is then append "true" or "false" to a newtextfile (with the correpsonding number).

Comment: The whole point to check if you have a number is because I suppose you have lines with something that cannot be a number like `1234 ABCD 456 ZZZZ 98989`. My answer takes a line, splits the line in the separate 'words' and pass each word to IsNumberValid to examine.

Comment: Sorry Steve I just didnt want to post my code of my validation of the numbers, I am validating whether or not these numbers represent a valid refrence. For instance it could be like a serial key, if it doesnt match then I need it to output false in a new textfile.

Comment: Well, where is the problem? Just remove the code in IsValidNumber and use your own code. The code before and after the call is indipendent from the way in which you validate the string passed in. It is just two loops with string splitting.

Comment: Or did you just want to validate the Whole line in just one spot?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
FileStream fsIn = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fsIn))
 {

     line = sr.ReadLine();

     while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(line)
     {
        line = sr.ReadLine();
       //call isNumberValid on each line, store results to list
     }
 }
```

Then print the list using `FileStream`.

As other people have mentioned, your `isNumberValid` method could make use of the `Int32.TryParse` method, but since you said your text file only contains numbers this may not be necessary. If you're just trying to match the number exactly, you can use `number == line`.

Comment: Its calling isNumberValid to check the numbers in the textfile thats bugging me.