# Using Stream Writer to Add Numbers in text file

Tags: c#, .net

I am using Stream Writer class and am trying to sum up all the numbers in my text file.
My text file format is below:

```
name | number
-------------
  a       2
  a       3
```

What I am trying to do is to print out the sum of the numbers but am struggling to grab the numbers. I was thinking about using a for loop to sum up the numbers but not sure where to start to grab the numbers only.

Comment: Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16551536/open-text-file-loop-through-contents-and-check-against as a starting point.

Comment: Also may be worth adding the pipe separator between the name and number on each line as well.  Then as you loop through the lines, split the content of each line one the pipe separator, grab the line[1] item and trip it then parse it as an int (if they are all int's).

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do something like the following:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("sample.txt");
int sum = 0;
foreach (string line in lines.Skip(2))
{
    sum += Convert.ToInt32(line.Trim().Split(' ').Last());
}
```

- First we create an empty `sum` variable of type `int` (if this needs to be `double` it can be easily swapped here, of course).
- `Skip(2)` skips the first two lines (header and line separator).
- `Trim()` removes leading or trailing spaces from the current line.
- `Split(' ')` splits the current line by a space character to break apart the `name` column from the `number` column (note that it actually creates additional empty columns as well because we split by a single space character).
- `Last()` to selects the last column, which in this case will always select the `number` column.
- `Convert.ToInt32()` converts the last column to an `int` type (which can be `double` instead if desired, as explained previously).